# Using JMeter to record program http requests

Tags: automated-testing, jmeter

Is JMeter designed to only record web browser traffic, or can it record http requests made by installed programs as well?

I set up JMeter as per these [instructions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf) and I do not see the web traffic of a particular application installed on my computer. I've set up the proxy settings in my system settings.

Comment: Tony, have you verified that your application is using the proxy settings?  For example, does your application fail if you try to run it when JMeter is not running?

Comment: I just tried application when JMeter and the application works, which upon further research is because the application communicates binary data with the server via some other port, which I assume is not going to be picked up by JMeter.

Comment: You can use HTTP over any port, and you can send binary data over HTTP.  JMeter supports protocols other than HTTP, e.g. FTP, but it does not automatically support _arbitrary_ protocols.  If the binary data uses a protocol JMeter does not support, you will need to extend JMeter.  I do not have any experience with that.

Comment: i am also facing this same problem, any way i got solution from your answer thanks

Answer (score 3):

With Jmeter you can record both HTTP/HTTPS traffic, also there is [Jmeter Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-load-testi/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi) which can record traffic without configuring JMeter.

To record web traffic in Jmeter:

- add Recording Controller into Test Plan
- add [HTTP Proxy Server](http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-superpower-http-proxy-server) into WorkBench
- click Start button.
- open browser network settings
- change proxy settings to localhost:8080
- remove localhost and 127.0.0.1 from "No proxy for" field.

To record any application IO:

- Set proxy (in Linux)

  ```
  export http_proxy=http://localhost:8080
  ```
- Or set proxy localhost:8080 if it's possible to change proxy settings in application.
- Start JMeter Proxy Server
- Use your application

**Note! Do not use JMeter as the proxy for any other request types - FTP, etc. - as the JMeter proxy cannot handle them.**

Comment: Bob - if this is the configuration to record non-browser HTTP/HTTPS traffic, could you make that a bit clearer in the answer for those of us who aren't as familiar with JMeter?

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I think these are the instructions for recording browser HTTP/HTTPS traffic.

Comment: @KatePaulk follow links if it's hard to understand. tony I added instruction related to recroding applications. Actually there is no any difference between recording browser or any application.

Comment: @BobMeliev, thank you for the extra information.